Are these slots in retaining wall bricks for rebars?
I'm building a retaining wall that's about 3ft tall and decided to use these bricks (6in x 16in x 11.5in). Are the slots in the middle for putting in rebars? If not what are they for?


Look much too small for useful rebar sizes.  Nice size for the string for centring/lining up.

I'm concerned about the wall staying stable just as a freestanding wall.  At 4ft high, you'll probably want to add some sort of additional support into your hillside to help hold things in place.  I have an 18" high wall around part of my vegetable garden, and over the course of a few years even that low height has started to bow out with the pressure of the dirt behind it, even with pins interlocking the layers of wall together.

@Milwrdfan Correction: the wall is actually 3ft tall and we will be backfilling the gap with 3/4 gravel for drainage.

Those are drainage channels.
The block is upside down.
The lip on the back edge hooks behind the lower row blocks, and keeps the block from sliding forward.

Good spot. I see now that the lip on the lower block has been removed.

Yeah I put them upside down for the picture and I removed the lips because those are the base layer.

@jsotola thanks for the clarification!

Followup question: where does the water go if those are drainage channels? won't it just be trapped in the blocks since they lay flat?

place two of the blocks side by side and look

removed the lips because those are the base layer ... isn't that pointless effort?

If I don't remove the lips they make it harder to level the base layer because they're at the bottom

I get that the channels connect when the blocks line up but it's still flat right? I guess the water will flow through the channels and makes its way out from in between the blocks?

the channels do not connect in a straight wall
